# rails 3, trying to use aws-sdk gem, cannot find any docs for methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

Trying to use the Amazon aws-sdk gem to upload files to S3.

I cannot find any docs on what methods are available to browse/create buckets and files.

The one and only sample they give on the github repo includes one example of creating a S3 bucket and writing a file, but contains no example of listing files in a bucket, setting permissions on a file in a bucket, or putting a file into an existing bucket, or how to copy a file referenced by a url into the bucket.

Does anyone know of sample code and/or a list of methods available for using the aws-sdk gem for ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best documentation I found was at:

http://rubydoc.info/github/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/master/frames

Click on the S3 link in the sidebar from there.

**Update**: to clarify, the class descriptions, methods, etc. are in a pulldown menu from the S3 link in the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks, but that's the same basic docs that doesn't show how to list file sin bucket, set permissions, put another file into an existing bucket, copy a file referenced by a url into a bucket (all of which it can do, but is not documented as to how)

Comment: The S3 link in the sidebar has a pulldown which gives details on all of the class methods, etc.  For example, S3::Bucket shows how to list stuff in a bucket.

Comment: allll right! thanks. would you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

I had to dig deep to find any useful documentation myself. Try these links:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html

https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby

http://rubydoc.info/github/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby/master/AWS/S3

The 3rd one is the most useful imo

Here is (much better) documentation for the aws-s3 gem, which I realize isn't the same, but it's a good reference

http://amazon.rubyforge.org/

Comment: At least it isnt just me having trouble. I've been using the aws-s3 gem and it works AND has docs. But was hoping to update to the aws-sdk for other capabilities but they have NO useful docs. (Why do they even bother releasing a gem with zero docs?) Shame all the examples you or I could find use the very same (small/grossly incomplete) sample.